# Check If User Liked Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used the following code, and still use in older apps that I have created in Facebook, to hide content from users until they like the Fan page the app resideds on in a tab.

```
$request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);
$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))
{
//Show Content
}else{
//Hide Content
}
```

However when i come to use this code now, It does not work. Doe's anyone know why this still works in my older apps, but will not work when I create newer apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does still work. It was an issue with the settings of the app, specifically the URL structure I had used.

Comment: what was the problem in the app settings?

Comment: It was an issue with the URL for the app, was not defining it correctly